# Dart Sort by dynamic class value

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to sort a list by a user-chosen value but I am getting the following error: `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'InventoryItem'.`

```
List<InventoryItem> sortInventory(List<InventoryItem> itemList, String sortBy) {
  itemList.sort((a, b) {
    return a[sortBy].toLowerCase().compareTo(b[sortBy].toLowerCase());
  });

  return itemList;
}
```

Comment: `itemList` is a list of `InventoryItem` so when you do sort, then `a` and `b` becomes `InventoryItem` objects. The error are telling you that you are then trying to call `[sortBy]` on `a` which are a `InventoryItem`.

Comment: If I do a.name or any other property of InventoryItem I get no errors. so how do I dynamically select the property?

Comment: Dart does not support the concept of selecting a property based on String or index position unless you are using `dart:mirrors` which only works in JIT mode and is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Define an `enum` for all the fields of `InventoryItem` that can be used in a sort.

Use that `enum` inside the sort function to `switch`.

The following (untested) code should point in the right direction:

```dart
enum SortBy { name, price, blabla }

List<InventoryItem> sortInventory(List<InventoryItem> itemList, SortBy sortBy) {
  itemList.sort((a, b) {
    switch (sortBy) {
      case SortBy.name:
        return a.name.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.name.toLowerCase());
      case SortBy.price:
        return a.price.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.price.toLowerCase());
      default:
        throw 'Cannot sort by: ' + sortBy.toString(); // = SortBy.blabla
    }
  });

  return itemList;
}
```

To let the user select the right `enum` / field, use a Flutter `DropdownButton` working with said `enum`.

Comment: It's what I'm using at the moment, was looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: @Trax If `sortBy` is a parameter with a fixed value when compiling, you could make it so it takes a `String Function(InventoryItem)` which is called to get the value that should be sorted on `a` and `b`. If so, you can call the sortInventory like e.g.: `sortInventory(list, (i) => i.name)` . It is cleaner but depends on if `sortBy` is something that should come from a text field specified by a user.